# Is it possible to check which of the last blocks is mined by me?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, block-explorer

**Input**: `monero_addr` - address of my wallet that I specified in my miner's config.

**Output**: `[2045661, 2045650, 2045630, ...]` - block's heights that was mined by me.

In which direction should I move to get this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `monero-wallet-cli` this is a breeze.

Start the wallet with your miner wallet:

```
monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file miner-wallet
```

Then execute:

```
show_transfers coinbase
```

Which will list all coinbase (i.e. block reward) transfers. The first column in the output has the block height.

Comment: How to make 100% sure that the transaction for the mined block is confirmed?

Comment: If it shows in `show_transfers coinbase` and is unlocked, it *is* confirmed.